# How i can i know if the login succeeded in the main activity?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a project in android studio in Java. I have a login page in the MainActivity and also DbHelper Class that saves db (connection to the firestore in google). I have a function in DBHelper class that checks the login, but i don't know how can i return a value.

this is the code in the MainActivity:

```
public void loginToDataBase (View view)
{
    String username, password;
    // Get the data from the user
    username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginUsername)).getText().toString();
    password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginPassword)).getText().toString();

    // Checking if one of the fields is empty
    if (username.equals("") || password.equals("") ) {
        setMessage("Please Fill in all fields");
        return;

    }

    db.doLogin(username, password);
}
```

this is the code in DBHelper, i don't know how to return a value to the MainActivity to see if the login was okay, i thought maybe return the userData but it didn't work.

```
public void doLogin(String username, String password)
{
    db.collection("Users")
            .whereEqualTo("username",username)
            .whereEqualTo("hashedPassword",password)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        SetStatus("Error: " + task.getException());
                        return;
                    }
                    if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                        SetStatus("Login & Password mismatch");
                        return;
                    }
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0);
                    if (document.getMetadata().isFromCache()) {
                        SetStatus("The Data is from cache. sorry");
                        return;
                    }

                    String firstName = document.get("firstName").toString();
                    String lastName = document.get("lastName").toString();
                    String username1 = document.get("username").toString();

                    Map<String, Object> userData = new HashMap<>();
                    userData.put("username", username1);
                    userData.put("firstName", firstName);
                    userData.put("lastName", lastName);

                    SetStatus("Welcome: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know how can I return a value"? Which value are you referring to? And as far as I can see both methods return `void`.

Comment: beacuse the method of calling to google is Asynchronous method, i cant return from there true for example. so i need to return if the login was succeeded, in order to know that, the method "doLogin" needs to return something so i can know.

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).